# mysql_install_db gives FATAL ERROR: Could not find my-default.cnf

Tags: mysql, database, installation

I've download MySQL and I'm trying to setup the MySQL grant tables, but when I type:

```
scripts/mysql_install_db --basedir=/usr/local
```

I get the error above.

I'm not sure how to fix it, as `my-default.cnf` is in the `support_files` directory and I believe I'm setting the `basedir` correctly.

(This is on mac btw)

Comment: check that file it is existed or not

Answer (score 9):

(I'm assuming you're using Homebrew, since I hit the same issue trying to do the same thing on Homebrew on my macbook)

I believe you need to point it to the actual mysql directory in the cellar as its basedir, not at /usr/local (since that's just things symlinked from the cellar dir).

So, in my case, I had to use:

```
$ mysql_install_db --basedir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.10
```

Comment: i am running into these errors with brew too,  and other errors.   brew....what a disaster.

Comment: OneSolitaryNoob... hardly? But yes the mysql process is somewhat confusing. Try running 'brew info mysql' and see if any of the options there help you.

Answer (score 3):

Need copy /usr/share/my.cnf
Try this:

```
sudo cp /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/share/mysql/my-default.cnf
sudo mysql_install_db
```

Its help for me on Ubuntu 14.04 and mysql 5.6.33

Comment: On Arch Linux I had to use `mysql_install_db --basedir=/usr` , and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

To extend to rascalking's answer, the current mysql installs to /usr/local/mysql/ via brew.

But to get over timestamp issue and the permission issue the full command will be:

```
sudo mysql_install_db --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
```

Don't forget to set your password first incase you skipped the instruction:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'new-password'
```